# Не получается подключиться к базе данных mssql

Tags: python, sql-server

Пытаюсь подключиться к базе данных на моем компьютере. Пользователь создан, и через Management studio я могу на него нормально зайти. При попытке из кода это сделать, летит ошибка. Год назад связывался с mssql, и там этот код срабатывал нормально, единственное, там не было instance и просто заходил напрямую на хост.

```
import pytds
with pytds.connect(dsn='qwer\\qwer', database='qwer', user='sa', password='12345', autocommit=True) as conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    print('ok')
    conn.close()
```

Вылетает следующая ошибка

```
pytds.tds_base.LoginError: ("Cannot connect to server 'KEFIR740': [WinError 10054] Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение", ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))
```

Пробовал по разному, и как в документации qwer[\qwer], но все равно сыпется ошибка

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте проверить следующее:

1. Пропинговать сервер с БД: ping -a <IP адрес>
2. Проверить доступен ли порт по которому хотите подключится к БД: telnet <IP адрс> <номер порта>
3. Проверить в настройках требует ли ваша БД ssl